# IsoMessage 8583 XML c#

Tags: c#, xml, iso, iso8583

While executing, I get the error at this location.
      `XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(BuildIsoMessage.Properties.Resources.Deneme);`//I Get the document from resources in this way.

```
       ` GenericPackager packager = new GenericPackager(doc.ToString());`
```

`An unhandled exception of type 'org.jpos.iso.ISOException' occurred in jpos.dll.Additional information: Error reading <!DOCTYPE isopackager PUBLIC "-//jPOS/jPOS Generic Packager DTD 1.0//EN" "http://jpos.org/dtd/generic-packager-1.0.dtd"[]>`

I am trying to build an ISO Message in c#. I converted Jar files into one dll file and using some of the namespaces 
`using org.jpos.util;
using org.jpos.iso;
using org.jpos.iso.channel;
using org.jpos.iso.packager;`
however I can not pack my xml file, it throws an error.

https://github.com/jpos/jPOS/blob/master/jpos/src/main/resources/packager/iso87ascii.xml
[image]

Comment: who the hell give me minus 1? Explain the reason instead of down voting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jpos dll worked fine when provided path like below

GenericValidatingPackager packager = new GenericValidatingPackager();
 packager.readFile("c:/isoxml/iso8583binary.xml");

Comment: good idea! but now it throws this error `Additional information: org.xml.sax.SAXException: SAX2 driver class org.apache.crimson.parser.XMLReaderImpl not found`

Comment: I solved the problem by downloading apache.crimson and parsing into dll with other files. @Pubudu you are the man, many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is too simple to use a 3rd party dll.  Use xml linq :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string xmlHeader =
                "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"no\"?>" +
                "<!DOCTYPE isopackager PUBLIC" +
                "        \"-//jPOS/jPOS Generic Packager DTD 1.0//EN\"" +
                "        \"http://jpos.org/dtd/generic-packager-1.0.dtd\" >" +

                "<!-- ISO 8583:1987 (ASCII) field descriptions for GenericPackager -->" +

                "<isopackager>" +
                "</isopackager>";


            //<isofield

            XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xmlHeader);
            XElement isoPackager = doc.Descendants("isopackager").FirstOrDefault();

            List<IsoField> isoFields = new List<IsoField>() {
                new IsoField() { id= 0, length= 4, name="MESSAGE TYPE INDICATOR", cClass = "org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"},
                new IsoField() { id= 1, length= 16, name="BIT MAP", cClass= "org.jpos.iso.IFA_BITMAP"},
                new IsoField() { id= 2, length= 19, name="PAN - PRIMARY ACCOUNT NUMBER", cClass= "org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLNUM"}
                };

            foreach (IsoField isofield in isoFields)
            {
                isoPackager.Add(new XElement("isofield", new object[] {
                    new XElement("id", isofield.id),
                    new XElement("length", isofield.length),
                    new XElement("name", isofield.name),
                    new XElement("class", isofield.cClass)
                }));

            }
            doc.Save(FILENAME);

        }
    }

    public class IsoField
    {
        public int id {get; set;}
        public int length { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string cClass { get; set; }
    }

}
```

Comment: it is great way to create an xml file but I already have an created xml file, the problem is `GenericPackager packager = new GenericPackager(doc.ToString());` does not accept the xml file.

Comment: Looks like generic packager want a stream.  So StringReader reader = new StringReader(doc.toString()); GenericPackager packager = new GenericPackager(reader);

Comment: Actually in Java  `InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/fields.xml");` done like that, I can not find a way to convert it into C#

Comment: The read it into a MemoryStream.  The memory stream want a byte[] so use MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(doc.ToString())); stream.Position = 0;  GenericPackager packager = new GenericPackager(stream);

Comment: I even tried   `MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("deneme.xml"));
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
            string text = reader.ReadToEnd();` but I get this exception
   `An unhandled exception of type 'org.jpos.iso.ISOException' occurred in jpos.dll

Additional information: Error reading deneme.xml `

Comment: using Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("deneme.xml") will just convert the string "deneme.xml" to bytes.  Ignore any errors using this code.  Can you test the code using my xml instead of yours.  Right now I suspect the xml you are feeding the packager is bad.