# GenericPackager can't read XML file in ISO Message

Tags: c#, asp.net, iso

I am trying to call in ISO Message from Website (ASP.NET). I imported all DLL and code. But while reading XML from **GenericPackager** class, file can't read exception is coming.

The same code is working fine in C# Windows application.

Here is the code:

```
IsoXML_Path = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~") + "PostCardFields.xml";
GenericPackager packager = new GenericPackager();
packager.readFile(IsoXML_Path);

 ISOMsg isoMsg = new ISOMsg();
 isoMsg.setPackager(packager);
```

Error in Exception:

> Error reading (PATH)\PostCardFields.xml
>   (org.xml.sax.SAXException: SAX2 driver class org.apache.crimson.parser.XMLReaderImpl not found
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.crimson.parser.XMLReaderImpl)

(PATH) is the path of my XML file in directory. File is exists on that path.

Comment: One can hardly help here. More context/information is needed. Please review [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and especially read the "Help others reproduce the problem" section.

Comment: _"file cant read exception is coming"_ - so, did you deploy the `MobilityPostCardFields.xml` file?

Comment: yes this xml file is available on path

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: The error appears to be coming from a Java component, not a C# component.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IsoMessage 8583 XML c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47151159/isomessage-8583-xml-c-sharp)

Comment: sorry ben, I didnt get you what does it mean "Possible duplicate od ISOMessage 8583 XML"